# Is there is a way to re-run failed suites immediately using protractor(Jasmine)

Tags: jasmine, protractor

If there is 10 suites are loaded for execution in jasmine, if 3rd suite fails, is it possible to re-run 3rd suite before 4th suite starts and continues execution.

Answer (score 0):

you can try using protractor-flake or protractor-retry packages.

https://www.npmjs.com/package/protractor-retry

https://www.npmjs.com/package/protractor-flake

Comment: I have gone through those module. Using those I can re- run failed script only after all the suites are executed (i.e loaded initially). But here the situation is to run the suite immediately it fails.